# Unable to call flask method from another flask method of same python file

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

Unable to call flask method from another flask method of same python file. For example, consider the code below

```
@app.route('/api/v1/employee/add', method = ['POST'])
def add_employee():
    req = request.json
    #add the employee to db

@app.route('/api/v1/employee', method = ['GET'])
def get_employee():
    data = json.loads(employee) #getting employee details from db
    add_employee() # unable to call this method as I am getting the data as null.
```

How to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flask Function will expect an http request. You can create command function without Flask app.route decorator. This will be helpful to separate functionality and http request .For example below:

```py
def add_employee():
    # Add Some Query here
    pass



@app.route('/api/v1/employee/add', method = ['POST'])
def http_employee():
    req = request.json
    add_employee()


@app.route('/api/v1/employee', method = ['GET'])
def get_employee():
    data = json.loads(employee) #getting employee details from db
    add_employee() # unable to call this method as I am getting the data as null.
```

Comment: still facing the same issue, All I tried is moved add_employee block of code as separate method and called inside POST API and GET API. POST API is working fine but still calling add_employee from GET API is throwing NoneType error.

Comment: This is because you need to return something to prevent flask throw NoneType error.